# How come "Not at all" means "Yes" in the following situation?

Tags: idioms

I've been watching The Mentalist today, and this part of a dialogue puzzled me:

> [1]: Do you think you could watch Howard [a dog] for me?
>
> [2]: Oh, not at all.
>
> [1]: I really appreciate it, thank you.

Now, it is clear from this dialogue and from what's going on on the screen that [2] agreed to watch the dog.

I checked Oxford and Cambridge dictionaries, and both state that *not at all* can be *used as a polite reply to an expression of thanks*, but this doesn't fit what's going on in the dialogue. It would also make sense if the question was worded as *Would you mind watching Howard for me?*, but it was not (I checked and double checked).

Is it common and/or normal that *not at all* is used as a positive reply? Is it an AmE thing? I'm almost certain I would have thought it was a "no" rather than a "yes" if somebody answered my request that way.

Comment: Are you sure that's what [1] initally said? I'd imagine it would be 'Do you mind watching Howard for me?' (or similar) in which case 'oh, not at all' would be a perfectly okay response.

Comment: Yes, I double checked it (I actually mentioned that in the question). It's a word-to-word transcript of the dialogue.

Comment: sarcasm is my only other (futile) guess...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it wasn't. It didn't sound sarcastic and further events in the episode indicated that [2] was, in fact, watching the dog.

Comment: In conversation, we often respond *as if* someone had said something other than they actually said, substituting one phrase for another. More classic examples are illogical items like "I could care less about Bob", which means "I *couldn't* care any less about Bob".  In this case, the response is to the un-asked "do you mind" / "would it bother you to" version of the question. Whether there is a formal term for this process, I don't know.

Comment: It's *The Mentalist* for heaven's sake! Patrick's always messing with people's minds, including turning what they say into what he wants to hear. There's no mystery of English usage here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns a dialog from a TV show called *The Mentalist.* It is not about English usage!

Comment: @torek Thanks! Would you mind making that an answer? I'd like to wait until tomorrow in case more answers come up, and then accept it.

Comment: @MarkHubbard what does this have to do with anything? It's still English. People ask about confusing sentences from books and movies all the time, how is this question any different?

Comment: Looks like davidlol beat me to it, and gave a term for it ("the implied question").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of answering the implied question, rather  than the actual question.

This [discussion](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/sure-as-a-reply-to-would-you-mind-doing-something.2004232/) on Word Reference looks at a common example where one person asks

> Would you mind doing X

and the answer is

> Sure.

The meaning of the reply is judged by tone and demeanour of the respondent, which if positive is answering the question in the form the responder would have asked it "Will you do X?"  The question is interpreted and the response given as if it had been phrased differently.

There is a difference between the literal, logical,  meaning and the conveyed, actual, meaning.  Literally and logically "would you mind" means one thing, but actually it is a conventional idiom for "please will you".

A common example is

> Can I steal one of your biscuits?

If the biscuit owner is happy for the person to eat the biscuit then the literal, logical answer is no - it is not logically possible to steal something if the owner is perfectly happy for you to eat it anyway,   but in practice people answer the implied question which is "please may I have a biscuit" and give the answer to the conveyed , actual, question

> Yes, please do.

Comment: Sorry sumelic, and thanks for pointing it out. I meant the implied link rather than the actual one.